# How to use Selenium and PhantomJS to click and upload a file on a webpage from Python?

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, upload, phantomjs

I'm trying to click the [Choose File] option and upload a specific file under the [Query] section of [this page](https://www.genome.jp/maple-bin/mapleSubmit.cgi?aType=sDirect) from Python.  I know that you can use `Selenium` with `PhantomJS` to dynamically load webpages and have "phantom" browser sessions.

**Can anyone describe the process necessary to do this? If possible, to direct me to any code that can guide me through this process?**

My ultimate goal is to get upload file and submit a job on this website.

[image]

I've inspected the HTML of the [Choose File] button and I found the source code that directs this action: 
[image]